# "message":"network byfn not found"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following-
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html

with manual configuration I installed the chain-code in the 4 peers

```
1. peer0.org1.example.com(anchor peer)
2. peer1.org1.example.com
3. peer0.org2.example.com(anchor peer)
4. peer1.org2.example.com
```

In a channel with id "first".

Now when I try to instantiate the chain-code I am getting the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a problem of the environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`. I solved this by adding a `.env` file in my project folder with the environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` set to `net`.

If that does not help, you can also check your `peer-base.yaml` file for the variable `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` and see if it has been set correctly or not. Your `peer-base.yaml` file should have environment block looking  something like this:

```
 - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # bridge network as the peers
  # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
  #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `COMPOSER_PROJECT_NAME` is not set.
When starting the docker containers,
update this command

```
CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

with below command:

```
CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME IMAGE_TAG=latest COMPOSER_PROJECT_NAME=byfn docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```